# Why is Vtyp less than Vmin on a CMOS chip

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, logic-gates, logic-level, nxp

Regarding the chip [74HC08](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT08.pdf)

On the table describing Static Characteristics (Section 9). Why is the typical V<sub>IH</sub> lower than the minimum value.
And vice versa for V<sub>IL</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is all about the required input levels into a logic device

The minimum value for \$V_{IH}\$ is the guaranteed value for a "1". In other words, if you equal or exceed this level the input circuit will definitely recognize it as a logical 1. Typically it might work a bit lower than this.

As for \$V_{IL}\$, the maximum value is that input level that would be definitely recognized as a logical zero. Typically this may be a tad higher.

If you look at this picture it might help: -

[image]

It describes inputs and outputs for a typical 5V logic scenario. Note how \$V_{OH}\$ (for an outputting device) is always bigger than \$V_{IH}\$ for a receiving device - this guarantees correct and unambiguous operation. This scenario would not be "spoiled" if \$V_{IL}\$ was a little bit bigger and \$V_{IH}\$ were a little bit smaller and, of course, this is where the typical values come in.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter that you should use in your design, is \$V_{min}\$, because this is the guaranteed value from the manufacturer.
\$V_{typ}\$ is a *typical value*, means that most devices operate with this value, but the manufacturer can't guarantee for all devices.
Then, \$V_{min}\$ is a little bit higher, and applies for all devices manufactured.